# Play framework : What is the best way to pass on scala template parameter to Javascript (angular)?

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, scala, playframework-2.0

Lets say I want to pass a List of strings to my template and create a ul by iterating over it. **And I don't want to use ng-init.**

**Action** :

```
 public static Result login(){

    List<String>Names = Arrays.asList("Tom","Dick","Harry");

    return ok(login.render(Names));
}
```

**login.scala.html**:

```
@(names: List[String])

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="app">

<body>

    <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>

<script>
    app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope){

        $scope.names = @Html(names); 
        //This does not work
        // Error : type mismatch; found : java.util.List[String] required: String

    });

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: That does not make any sense. Even if `@Html` would convert that list to an ul list you would get a syntax error. Maybe you want to convert that to an js list? Please make more clear what you want to achieve

Comment: You may not know but, `@Html` is just writing given value on output *without* formatting it automatically as HTML (as this function specifically expect given value to by manually formatted as HTML). So it won't in any case do such magic conversion that would add `<ul>` tags.

Comment: @Salem , applicius : Pardon me for not being explicit here. I'm trying to update $scope.names which implicitly means that I'd need it as a JS array(or Object, that will work too). Angular will use the array 'names' to create <ul> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, you could use Scala formating before passing to `@Html` to display it without escaping.

```
<!-- language: scala -->
@Html(names.mkString("[",",","]"))
// Formats list by starting with '[', ending with ']', with ',' as separator
// aka JS format for array

@Html(names.mkString("""["""", """","""", """"]"""))
// wraps array values with ""
```

N.B. If your string values contain " character, extra formatting would be required.

Comment: Didn't work!
@Html(names.mkString("[",",","]"))                               
// Error : Tom is not defined                                       
@Html(names.mkString("""["", """","""", """"]"))                    
// Error : unclosed multi-line string literal

Comment: First error doesn't correspond to mentioned code, which doesn't include any `Tom`, so check yourself in your code how it's written. Second one is an obvious typo (if not look at edited answer, and at Scala doc about String).

Comment: As said, you need to adapt formatting according your values, and wanted output. If it work, please accept the answer.

Comment: Well, for the first one, 'Tom' is the first value in the List in the code above. So I'm not sure the first part of your answer is proper. But I get the second option working. thanks much! I'm also having to pass a variety of data formats. Next one being List of objects. I'm still not getting the hang of it as to why are we using so many double quotes. So not sure how to do it for objects. Will be grateful for more inputs.